# Is it possible to make two sides of the plane transparent in P5JS?

Tags: p5.js

Is it possible to make two sides of the plane transparent in P5JS?

I tried use tint on texture but it only works for one side.

```
texture(img);
plane(width, height);
tint(255, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean making a plane left and one more to right? This code helps

```
var img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://editor.p5js.org/favicon.ico");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  orbitControl();
  push();
  noStroke();
  texture(img);
  rotateY(45);
  push()
  plane(width - 50, height - 50);
  pop();
  push();
  translate(-((width / 2) - 50), 0, -170);
  rotateY(-90);
  plane(width - 50, height - 50);
  pop();
  push();
  translate(width - 230, 0, -170);
  rotateY(90);
  plane(width - 50, height - 50);
  pop();
  pop();
}
```